# Not able to free memory from function

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, valgrind

I have a `C` program that implements trees. my cleanup function looks like this:

```
void cleanup_tree( TreeNode* root ){
        printf("Called\n");
        if(root->left!=NULL){
                cleanup_tree(root->left);

        }   

        if(root->right!= NULL){
                cleanup_tree(root->right);
        }   

        if(root->right==NULL &&root->left==NULL) {
                /*free(root);*/
                free(root->word);
                free(root);
                root = NULL;
        }   

}
```

My Tree struct has

```
typedef struct TreeNode_st {
    char *word;                   // the word held in this node
    unsigned int frequency;       // how many times it has been seen
    struct TreeNode_st *left;     // node's left child
    struct TreeNode_st *right;    // node's right child
} TreeNode;
```

I am initialising a tree like this :

```
TreeNode* initTreeNode(){
        TreeNode *mainNode=     (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        mainNode->frequency = 0 ;
        mainNode->word = NULL;
        mainNode->left = NULL;
        mainNode->right = NULL;
        return mainNode;

}
```

in my `main`, I have called

```
TreeNode *mainNode =initTreeNode();
```

and I'm doing operations on it , and just before program exit, i called

```
cleanup_tree(mainNode);
```

Valgrind reported memory leaks, so just to test , i did 
I put
 `printf("~~~FINAL NULL TEST  %s",mainNode->left->right->word);`
below my cleanup_tree line, 
And i'm able to see the word even now.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Looks like `if(root->right==NULL &&root->left==NULL) {` only frees nodes with no children?

Comment: i am calling that function recursively, so It should to go the edges, set them free, so the parent will now be a node that has no children, and it will go up to the root

Comment: The variables don't set themselfs magically to `NULL` though.

Comment: but i am setting a non null ROOT to NULL after freeing it.

Comment: That's a local variable, so not visible outside of your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. You pass it a pointer-to-a-pointer: `void cleanup_tree( TreeNode **root)`
2. You set the fields to NULL after the cleanup returns:

Currently, the changes made by the function are not reflected in the node parameter you passed.

Ad 2:

```
cleanup_tree(root->right);
root->right= NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be under the impression that setting `root = NULL` at the end of this function will be visible in the calling function so that the third `if` block gets called.  That's not the case.

You want to always `free()`  the `word` as well as the node itself.

```
void cleanup_tree( TreeNode* root ){
        printf("Called\n");
        if(root->left!=NULL){
                cleanup_tree(root->left);
        }   

        if(root->right!= NULL){
                cleanup_tree(root->right);
        }   
        free(root->word);
        free(root);
}
```

Comment: when I removed my if (left node and right node are both null) condition , i get segmentation fault

Comment: @harvey_slash There must be some other issue, then.  What does valgrind say?

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie's answer worked, 
if im setting left and right to NULL, valgrind is happy